# Ubuntu Nginx uwsgi socket not work

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to set up my Django(2.0) project with nginx and uwsgi, but it just fails when running:

```
uwsgi --socket :8001 --wsgi-file test.py
```

which follows https://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

it's failed, can not connect server ,
but

`uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file test.py` is ok

here is my uwsgi log:

```
    (venv) ubuntu@VM-49-116-ubuntu:~/code/blog/mmxy$ uwsgi --socket :8001 --wsgi-file test.py
    *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17 (64bit) on [Wed Apr 11 02:19:40 2018] ***
    compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 09 April 2018 17:37:14
    os: Linux-4.4.0-91-generic #114-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 8 11:56:56 UTC 2017
    nodename: VM-49-116-ubuntu
    machine: x86_64
    clock source: unix
    detected number of CPU cores: 1
    current working directory: /home/ubuntu/code/blog/mmxy
    detected binary path: /home/ubuntu/code/blog/venv/bin/uwsgi
    !!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
    *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
    your processes number limit is 3306
    your memory page size is 4096 bytes
    detected max file descriptor number: 1024
    lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
    thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
    uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :8001 fd 3
    Python version: 3.6.4 (default, Apr 10 2018, 00:02:46)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
    *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
    Python main interpreter initialized at 0xe92290
    your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
    your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
    mapped 72920 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
    *** Operational MODE: single process ***
    WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0xe92290 pid: 8870 (default app)
    *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
    spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 8870, cores: 1)
```

nginx conf:

```
    upstream django {
        # server unix:///tmp/mmxy.sock;
        server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
    }


    server {

        listen      8000;
        server_name 140.143.242.243;
        # server_name sususuus.xyz;
        charset     utf-8;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        # max upload size
        client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

        # Django media
        location /media  {
            alias /home/ubuntu/code/blog/mmxy/media;
        }

        location /static {
            alias /home/ubuntu/code/blog/mmxy/static;
        }

        # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
        location / {
            uwsgi_pass  django;
            include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        }
    }
```

nginx has 'Welcome to nginx' when I connect my servername

i think my nginx conf has something wrong but it same as the documentation

Comment: Where is that 'nginx conf' file located?

Comment: @Alasdair in my django project  and by `sudo ln -s ~/path/to/your/mysite/mysite_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` link to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/,  \n see: `ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` list:
default  mmxy_nginx.conf

Comment: did you ever solve?

Comment: So, was rhe problem solved?